# How can I prevent jQuery DataTable plugin from sending all the parameters to the server?

Tags: jquery, url, get, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables to build a table with some data from the server. The data is brought automatically using Ajax source, and I am using the server side to perform the pagination.

This are my columns and table initializations :

```
var dTColumns = [];

jQuery.each(inputData.columns, function(key, value){
  dTColumns.push({ 
    "bVisible": key<4, 
    "bSortable":false,
    "aTargets": [ key ],
    "mData": value["fieldName"]
  });
});

jQuery(table).dataTable({
  "aoColumnDefs": dTColumns,
  "bProcessing" : true,
  "sAjaxSource" : inputData.serverURL,
  "bServerSide": true,
  "sAjaxDataProp" : inputData.resultsRootAttribute
});
```

The problem is that I am using GET requests for all table operations (the searches that are triggered by using the navigation and sorting systems) and I noticed that ALL THE COLUMNS are placed inside the URL (this happens also in their example).

The problem is that I have 200+ columns in my table (only the first five are displayed), and the plugin populates the URL with 4 fields for each column.

**How can I prevent DataTables from placing all those parameters in the URL ? (I don't need sorting and searching functionality for the columns).**

**The answer :**
When initializing the table, you can add your custom way of performing the communication with the server. Inside this method, you can modify the *aoData* object which is an array with all the parameters that are being sent to the server.

You can find an example [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7060/passing-url-parameters-server-side/p1)!

Answer (score 1):

When initializing the table, you can add your custom way of performing the communication with the server. Inside this method, you can modify the *aoData* object which is an array with all the parameters that are being sent to the server.

You can find an example [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7060/passing-url-parameters-server-side/p1)!